# Maximum limit exceeded in hive while using partition table

Tags: hiveql

In  one of my querying requirements in hive I have used partitioning but I get an error as shown below:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE bldgpartitioned PARTITION(statname)
 SELECT  rilid ,featurecode, lgno, dgname, statname ,shape from bldg;
```

> The maximum path component name limit of statname :10002 is exceeded: limit=255 length=408

Please do let if I can increase the maximum limit specified as as shown above.

Comment: share `bldgpartitioned ` and `bldg` tables schema in question...

Comment: 1:describe bldgpartitioned;
OK
riluniqueid             string                  from deserializer
rilfeaturecode          string                  from deserializer
bldgno                  string                  from deserializer
bldgname                string                  from deserializer
shape                   binary                  from deserializer
statename               string

# Partition Information
# col_name              data_type               comment

Comment: describe bldgpartitioned;
OK
riluniqueid             string                  
rilfeaturecode          string                  
bldgno                  string                  
bldgname                string                  from deserializer
shape                   binary                  from deserializer
statename               string

# Partition Information
# col_name              data_type               comment

Comment: please find the schema for building :riluniqueid             string                  
rilfeaturecode          string                  
bldgno                  string                  
bldgname                string                  
statename               string                  
shape                   binary

Comment: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

Comment: this is how the error look like:            org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/hadoop/.staging/job_1466750866233_0297/libjars/spatial-sdk-hadoop.jar could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 6 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.